# CakePHP Blackhole Security Error

Tags: php, security, cakephp

I'm using Cakephp 2.3.0 and the Security component in my application. The login page displays correctly, but after post request, it goes to blackholdCallback with `auth` as error

but when I **unlockedAction** this login, and post data again, it authenticates and goes to my dashboard. What could be an issue ? How could I login into system without using unlockedAction.
Its very important as maximum user will try to enter system from this particualar action and I can't leave it unlocked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@learner cakephp 2015.first make sure you have closed the form  in you view.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create(); ?>

<!-- Form elements go here -->


<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

If you are using SecurityComponent in your application you should always end your forms with end().

ref:http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply.